# Haskell - Non-exhaustive pattern for a reason I don't understand

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, functional-programming, matching

So I'm trying to write a function that, given two lists of integers, adds the ith even number of each list and returns them in another list. In case one of the list doesn't have an ith even number, a 0 is considered. For example, if the lists are [1,2,1,4,6] and [2,2], it returns [4,6,6] ([2+2,4+2,6+0]). I have the following code:

```
addEven :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] 
addEeven [] [] = []
addEeven (x:xs) [] = filter (\g -> g `mod`2 == 0) (x:xs)
addEven [] (y:ys) = filter (\g -> g `mod` 2 == 0) (y:ys)
addEven (x:xs) (y:ys) = (a + b):(addEven as bs)
                        where 
                          (a:as) = filter (\g -> g `mod` 2 == 0) (x:xs)
                          (b:bs) = filter (\g -> g `mod` 2 == 0) (y:ys)
```

When I run that with the previous example, I get:

```
[4,6*** Exception: ex.hs:(4,1)-(8,101): Non-exhaustive patterns in function addEven
```

I really can't see what I'm missing, since it doesn't work with any input I throw at it.

Comment: A `filter` might eliminate elements, hence `filter (\g -> g `mod` 2 == 0) (x:xs)` is not said to return any elements, and thus the patterns `(a:as)` and `(b:bs)` might fail.

Comment: I see you have answers already, giving better ways to write this function - but the actual reason for the error message, which doesn't seem to have been picked up, is that in 2 of your patterns you misspell `addEven` as `addEeven`

Answer (score 1):

A `filter` might eliminate elements, hence `filter (\g -> g`mod`2 == 0)` is not said to return any elements, and thus the patterns `(a:as)` and `(b:bs)` might fail.

That being said, I think you make the problem too complex here. You can first define a helper function that adds two elements of a list:

```
addList :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
addList (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+y) : addList xs ys
addList xs [] = xs
addList [] ys = ys
```

Then we do the filter on the two parameters, and make a function `addEven` that looks like:

```
addEven :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
addEven xs ys = addList (filter even xs) (filter even ys)
```

or with [**`on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
import Data.Function(on)

addEven :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
addEven = addList `on` filter even
```

Answer (score 0):

While using `filter` is very instinctive in this case, perhaps using `filter` twice and then summing up the results might be slightly ineffficient for large lists. Why don't we do the job all at once for a change..?

```
addMatches :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
addMatches [] [] = []
addMatches [] ys = filter even ys
addMatches xs [] = filter even xs
addMatches xs ys = first [] xs ys
                   where
                   first :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
                   first rs [] ys     = rs ++ filter even ys
                   first rs (x:xs) ys = rs ++ if even x then second [x] xs ys
                                                        else first [] xs ys
                   second :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
                   second [r] xs []     = [r] ++ filter even xs
                   second [r] xs (y:ys) = if even y then first [r+y] xs ys
                                                    else second [r] xs ys

λ> addMatches [1,2,1,4,6] [2,2]
[4,6,6]
```